# Database design for stock like order/trade system

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I've spent a lot of time trying to make a trading system that performs well with MariaDB, but I can't figure it out.

What I'm trying to do is to replicate an order book system like the one often used for stock trading. You can add a buy or sell order at a given price, and if there is anything at that price or better a trade is executed.

Example:

1. User 1 publishes a sell order for 10 apples at $10/ea.
2. User 2 publishes a sell order for 5 apples at $8/ea.
3. User 3 publishes a sell order for 5 apples at $10/ea.
4. User 4 publishes a buy order for 5 apples at $8/ea. Trade is
   completed.
5. User 5 publishes a buy order for 13 apples at $10/ea. Trade is
   completed.
6. User 3 has the only published order left that sells 2 apples at $10/ea.

What I've tried so far is this table:

```
+------------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type                   | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11) unsigned       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id    | int(11) unsigned       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| ticker_id  | int(11) unsigned       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| count      | int(11)                | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| price      | decimal(19,4) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at | datetime               | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | datetime               | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Count is a negative number when it's a buy order, and a positive when it's a sell order.

This is the query I'm using when selling to match with buyers(greater/less and price ordering is flipped for matching with sellers):

```
SELECT `id`, ABS(`count`), `price` FROM trade_orders 
WHERE `ticker_id` = ? AND `count` < 0 AND `price` >= ? 
ORDER BY `price` DESC, `updated_at` ASC FOR UPDATE
```

Results are looped over. If there are buy orders that pays enough, then one of these queries are executed depending on the order sizes:

```
DELETE FROM trade_orders WHERE `id` = ? AND `count` = ? LIMIT 1

UPDATE trade_orders SET `count` = `count` + ?
WHERE `id` = ? AND `count` < ? LIMIT 1
```

Then, the remainder of the order is published:

```
INSERT INTO trade_orders (user_id, ticker_id, count, price, created_at, updated_at) 
VALUE (?, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), NOW())
```

This is wrapped up in a transaction that is rolled back in case of a deadlock.

The performance drops off really fast and goes from ~600 trades/sec using 2 threads to ~150 trades/sec when the amount of rows with a given ticker_id reaches ~15K. By 100K rows the performance is way below 10 trades/sec. It's the select query that is slow.

With 22K rows for a ticker_id, this is what ANALYZE shows:

```
mysql> ANALYZE     SELECT `id`, ABS(`count`), `price` FROM trade_orders     WHERE `ticker_id` = 1 AND `count` < 0 AND `price` >= 500     ORDER BY `price` DESC, `updated_at` ASC FOR UPDATE;
+------+-------------+--------------+------+-----------------------+-----------+---------+-------+-------+--------+----------+------------+-----------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table        | type | possible_keys         | key       | key_len | ref   | rows  | r_rows | filtered | r_filtered | Extra                       |
+------+-------------+--------------+------+-----------------------+-----------+---------+-------+-------+--------+----------+------------+-----------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | trade_orders | ref  | ticker_id,count,price | ticker_id | 4       | const | 10918 |   0.00 |   100.00 |     100.00 | Using where; Using filesort |
+------+-------------+--------------+------+-----------------------+-----------+---------+-------+-------+--------+----------+------------+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

Profiling shows that creation of sort index is the slow part:

```
SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 1;
+--------------------------------+----------+
| Status                         | Duration |
+--------------------------------+----------+
| Starting                       | 0.000085 |
| Waiting for query cache lock   | 0.000004 |
| Init                           | 0.000004 |
| Checking query cache for query | 0.000067 |
| Checking permissions           | 0.000008 |
| Opening tables                 | 0.000015 |
| After opening tables           | 0.000026 |
| System lock                    | 0.000008 |
| Table lock                     | 0.000006 |
| Init                           | 0.000022 |
| Optimizing                     | 0.000013 |
| Statistics                     | 0.000058 |
| Preparing                      | 0.000016 |
| Sorting result                 | 0.000007 |
| Executing                      | 0.000004 |
| Sending data                   | 0.000006 |
| Creating sort index            | 0.023916 |
| End of update loop             | 0.000024 |
| Query end                      | 0.000005 |
| Commit                         | 0.000032 |
| Closing tables                 | 0.000005 |
| Unlocking tables               | 0.000002 |
| Closing tables                 | 0.000005 |
| Starting cleanup               | 0.000002 |
| Freeing items                  | 0.000005 |
| Updating status                | 0.000043 |
| Reset for next command         | 0.000002 |
+--------------------------------+----------+
27 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Does anyone know how this should be done/designed for good performance even if there is 100K rows for a given ticker_id? I've been searching, but there is little to find on something like this. Never been in a situation like this where I need to ensure that there is never a buy row with a higher price than a sell row, or vice versa.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me out. If not a solution, then at least some pointers.

Comment: What indexes do you currently have on the table(s)? Can you show the full create table statement?

Comment: The table is in the post, none of them are multicolumn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I think you will find that Profiling is useless.)

Replace your index on `ticker_id` with these two composite indexes:

```
 INDEX(ticker_id, cost)
 INDEX(ticker_id, price)
```

The Optimizer will pick one of those (based on statistics); either will be more selective than what you have now.

```
WHERE `ticker_id` = ? AND `count` < 0 AND `price` >= ?
```

has two ranges.  This makes optimization difficult.  I see two workarounds.

Plan A:  Move the buy/sell flag to `price`:

```
WHERE `ticker_id` = ? AND `price` <= ?

INDEX(ticker_id, price)
```

Plan B:  Move the flag into a separate column:

```
buy_sell ENUM('buy','sell') NOT NULL

WHERE `ticker_id` = ? AND buy_sell ? AND `price` >= ?

INDEX(ticker_id, buy_sell, price)
```

(I prefer Plan A, but can't decide whether it performs better.)

You have two queries, correct?  With the inequalities and ordering flipped?  If it is possible make *both* queries each order the same, there may be an even better approach.  That is

```
ORDER BY price DESC, updated_at DESC  -- for one case
ORDER BY price ASC , updated_at ASC   -- for the other
```

Then, one of these may better optimize both cases:

```
INDEX(ticker_id, price, updated_at)
INDEX(ticker_id, buy_sell, price, updated_at)
```

(depending on whether `buy_sell` is still needed.)